# PayPal IPN missing shipping fields

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an ecommerce application that uses the cart upload method with various client paypal account and an IPN handler to validate the order.

Cart data being sent to paypal contains the shipping_x fields indicating the shipping charge per cart item.

After checkout IPNs from some of clients paypal accounts are missing the mc_shippingx fields for each cart line item.

Is there a setting inside a paypal account that would prevent mc_shippingx fields from being sent?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with paypal according to a response I received from their support site.

> Thank you for contacting Merchant Technical Support.
>
> Unfortunately, the problem you're experiencing is being caused by some technical issues with the PayPal system. Our engineers are currently working diligently on a solution to this problem. I am going to assign this ticket to our internal engineering ticket so that when the problem is resolved, you will be notified of its completion right away.

I would suggest anyone else with a similar issue submit a ticket at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ in hopes they resolve this issue quickly